# Getting Started with Spring framework 

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I am a php developer. Now i want to start development in j2ee also. Please suggest a better tutorial to start with springframe work.

Comment: See related questions on this page e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538443/getting-started-with-spring-framework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring framework consists from many modules. For quick overview read article on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework).

For start I suggest my favorite site is [springbyexample](http://www.springbyexample.org/) or [Spring-MVC-step-by-step](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/)

Or take a look for similar questions on this site:

- [getting started with spring framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538443/getting-started-with-spring-framework)
- [Spring MVC New getting started tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961462/spring-mvc-new-getting-started-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add vaannila tutorial. I have started Java EE spring recently like you and this website really help me. Good point that it's also treat hibernate !

[vaannila tutorial (Spring/hibernate/Strut1&2 ...)](http://www.vaannila.com)

Answer (score 0):

[springsourcery.org](http://springsourcery.org) may help.  There are plenty of tutorials and examples on this site which will help someone starting with Spring.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail?